# std::bind arguments not matching function parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm trying to pass a socket along a connection handshake, and use `std::bind` to do so. The compile issue I'm getting (in one continuous block, which I've added spaces to for readability) is:

```
'std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::_Bind(_Functor&&, _Args&& ...) 

[with _Args = {socket_state**, std::function<void(socket_state*)>&, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::executor>&, boost::asio::io_context&}; 

_Functor = void (*)(socket_state*, std::function<void(socket_state*)>&, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, boost::asio::io_context&); 

_Bound_args = {socket_state**, std::function<void(socket_state*)>, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::executor>, boost::asio::io_context}]':
```

My code is below, with the error appearing to nag at the `std::bind` arguments given to  `boost::asio::acceptor.async_accept(socket, ...)` and the parameters for the `accept_new_client` method

```
    void start_server(std::function<void(socket_state*)>& func, tcp::acceptor& acceptor, boost::asio::io_context& context)
    {
        acceptor.listen();
        // Start client connection loop
        networking::wait_for_client(func, acceptor, context);
    }

    void wait_for_client(std::function<void(socket_state*)>& func, tcp::acceptor& acceptor, boost::asio::io_context& context)
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(context);

        // socket_state is its own class which links a particular socket with an ID and buffer data
        // it also holds a function to indicate which part of the connection handshake it needs to go to next
        socket_state* state = new socket_state(func, &socket);
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, std::bind(&networking::accept_new_client, state, func, acceptor, context));
    }

    void accept_new_client(socket_state* state, std::function<void(socket_state*)>& func, tcp::acceptor& acceptor, boost::asio::io_context& context)
    {
            state->on_network_action(state);
            wait_for_client(func, acceptor, context);
    }
```

It seems like they would match, but you can see the error state my `std::bind` arguments are `socket_state**` instead of `socket_state*`, and `boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::executor>&` instead of `boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&`.

I have no idea what the "with _Args" vs. "_Bound_args" is either.

Comment: It's very suspicious that you are storing a pointer to the local variable `socket` in a structure allocated on the heap. As soon as `wait_for_client` returns, that local variable will be destroyed, leaving `socket_state` with a dangling pointer.

Comment: The error message suggests that you are passing `socket_state**` (two stars) to `std::bind`, while the function you are binding expects `socket_state*` (one star). The error message doesn't match the code shown; it must be different from the code you are actually compiling.

Comment: I'm very confused because the exact code snippet is what is being compiled. I've made changes to the snippet (like adding & behind some of the std::bind arguments) and it changes the error message, so it must be direct to the code I'm compiling. Also would storing a smart pointer instead be the move?

Comment: What's the exact and complete error message? You only showed a part of it - missing is the actual message where the compiler says what it believes is wrong. I'm not familiar with `boost::asio`, but a [quick glance](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html) appears to suggest that the callback is expected to take `const boost::system::error_code& error` parameter; yours doesn't. Perhaps this is the source of the error.

Comment: Also, you may want to use a lambda in place of `bind`, as in `acceptor.async_accept(socket, [=]() { networking::accept_new_client(state, func, acceptor, context); });` If nothing else, it tends to produce more comprehensible error messages.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But using bind expressions can be safer in propagating associated handler executors (ADL again).

Comment: @ttc100 What is `networking`? It matters a lot whether it is a class or a namespace

Comment: @sehe I'm not sure I understand. What kind of danger do you believe a lambda poses and `std::bind` mitigates?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Lambdas will not have nameable types. Even though they may wrap your handler type that has associated allocator/executor the lambda type will not propagate that, though a bind expression will (by virtue of ADL, becuase the handler type will be in the named type of the bind expression). Or at least this used to be the case with asio_handler_invoke and friends. (I should ready the math in the new executor model)

Comment: @sehe OK, I'll stop arguing here. The consideration appears specific to `boost::asio`, which I'm not at all familiar with and have no idea what "allocator/executor" is.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Actually, I think that is the achilles heel of the whole design of Asio. It's awesome, and of unparalleled flexibility, but there are many surprising subtle effects like this. I think things have become a lot better with the new executor model, so there's that.

Comment: @sehe `networking` is a namespace which serves as an abstraction for a server.cpp class to make use of. @IgorTandetnik The full error was literal hundreds of lines; the snippet I posted was the first portion and seemed likely to be the root of where everything else trickled down. In any case it is resolved now with the help of sehe. I appreciate your discussion here, it was insightful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many problems in this code.

The shared pointer seems to be at the wrong level of abstraction. You would want the entire "connection" type to be of shared lifetime, not just the socket. In your case, `socket_state` is a good candidate.

Regardless, your socket is a local variable that you pass a stale pointer to inside `socket_state`. Socket-state looks like it will necessarily be leaked.

So that will never work already.

Next up, the bind is binding all parameters eagerly, leaving a nullary signature. That's not what [any overload](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_12_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept.html) accepts [no pun intended]. You need to match

- [AcceptHandler](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_12_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AcceptHandler.html) or
- [MoveAcceptHandler](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_12_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MoveAcceptHandler.html)

Let's go for AcceptHandler. Also, let's not bind all the redundant args (`func` was already in the socket_state`remember,`io_context` is overshared etc.).

In general it looks like you need to develop confidence in knowing *where your state is*. E.g. this line is is symptomatic:

```
state->on_network_action(state);
```

Since `on_network_action` is a member function of `socket_state`, there should never be any need to pass the `state` as an argument (it will be `this` implicitly). The same thing goes for `acceptor` and `contest` in all occurrences.

### Demo

Fixing all the above, using std::shared_ptr and bind (you already did), notice the `placeholder::_1` to accept the error_code etc.)

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04e5a4c2b233ac76)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using boost::system::error_code;
using ba::ip::tcp;

struct socket_state;
using Callback = std::function<void(socket_state&)>;

struct socket_state : std::enable_shared_from_this<socket_state> {
    Callback _callback;
    tcp::socket _socket;

    template <typename Executor>
    socket_state(Callback cb, Executor ex) : _callback(cb)
                                           , _socket(ex)
    {
    }

    void on_network_action() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct networking {
    using StatePtr = std::shared_ptr<socket_state>;

    explicit networking(ba::io_context& ctx, Callback callback)
        : context(ctx)
        , callback(callback)
    {
    }

    ba::io_context& context;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor {context, {{}, 8989}};
    Callback callback;

    void start_server()
    {
        std::cout << "start_server" << std::endl;
        acceptor.listen();
        wait_for_client(); // Start client connection loop
    }

    void stop_server() {
        std::cout << "stop_server" << std::endl;
        acceptor.cancel();
        acceptor.close();
    }

    void wait_for_client()
    {
        std::cout << "wait_for_client" << std::endl;
        // socket_state is its own class which links a particular socket with
        // an ID and buffer data it also holds a function to indicate which
        // part of the connection handshake it needs to go to next
        auto state =
            std::make_shared<socket_state>(callback, context.get_executor());

        acceptor.async_accept(state->_socket,
                              std::bind(&networking::accept_new_client, this,
                                        std::placeholders::_1, state));
    }

    void accept_new_client(error_code ec, StatePtr state)
    {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "accept_new_client " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "accept_new_client " << state->_socket.remote_endpoint()
                  << std::endl;
        state->on_network_action();
        wait_for_client();
    }
};

int main() {
    ba::io_context ctx;
    networking server(ctx, [](socket_state&) {
        std::cout << "This is our callback" << std::endl;
    });

    server.start_server();

    ctx.run_for(5s);

    server.stop_server();
    ctx.run();
}
```

With some random connections:

```
start_server
wait_for_client
accept_new_client 127.0.0.1:54376
void socket_state::on_network_action()
wait_for_client
accept_new_client 127.0.0.1:54378
void socket_state::on_network_action()
wait_for_client
accept_new_client 127.0.0.1:54380
void socket_state::on_network_action()
wait_for_client
accept_new_client 127.0.0.1:54382
void socket_state::on_network_action()
wait_for_client
stop_server
accept_new_client Operation canceled
```

Note that version makes the comments

```
// socket_state is its own class which links a particular socket with
// an ID and buffer data it also holds a function to indicate which
// part of the connection handshake it needs to go to next
```

no longer complete lies :)

Comment: If you've made it this far, maybe you'll enjoy a version with some judicious renames, not hardcoding the port in the `Server`, more consistent executor use, illustrating how to initiate a strand per session: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2517741f7d28074

Comment: "In general it looks like you need to develop confidence in knowing where your state is" - indeed, before I was hazily writing what seemed good with no real footing of what I was doing. It feels like this answer has put my footing on the ground in terms of actually seeing what is going on with my socket_state and others (io_context and acceptors). Thank you for the clear and thorough answer.